# Group By Retrieve 3 Values

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, sql-function

I have following query

```
SELECT  Cod ,
        MIN(Id) AS id_Min,
        MAX(Id) AS id_Max,
        -- retrieve value in the middle,
        COUNT(*) AS Tot

FROM    Table a ( NOLOCK )        
GROUP BY Cod
HAVING  COUNT(*)=3
```

how could i retrieve value between min and max as i have done for min and max?

EXAMPLES

```
Cod      |  Id

Stack       10
Stack       15
Stack       11
Overflow    100
Overflow    120
Overflow    15
```

Required output

```
Cod         | Min   | Value_In_The_Middle  |    Max

Stack         10          11                    15
Overflow      15          100                   120
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't tested this but I think this would work

```
SELECT  Cod ,
        MIN(Id) AS id__Min,
        MAX(Id) AS id_Max,
        SUM(ID)-MAX(Id)-MIN(Id) as id_Middle,
        COUNT(*) AS Tot
FROM    Table a ( NOLOCK )        
GROUP BY Cod
HAVING  COUNT(*)=3
```

This trick only works when you have 3 values and the SUM() doesn't overflow (like [Bogdan Sahlean](https://stackoverflow.com/users/924077/bogdan-sahlean) points out in the comments).

Comment: @NikolaMarkovinović, yes you're right. I already corrected it.

Comment: +1 This is a neat way but it works only if `SUM` doesn't overflow: `SELECT SUM(T.C) FROM (VALUES(CONVERT(INT,2000000000)), (CONVERT(INT,2000000001))) T(C)`.

Comment: @Luigi: this is a different story. Write another question.