# Group By Retrieve 4 Values

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, aggregate-functions

I have the following query

```
SELECT  Cod ,
        MIN(Id) AS id_Min,
        -- retrieve value min in the middle as id_Min_Middle,
        -- retrieve value max in the middle as id_Max_Middle,
        MAX(Id) AS id_Max,            
        COUNT(*) AS Tot
FROM    Table a ( NOLOCK )        
GROUP BY Cod
HAVING  COUNT(*)=4
```

How could I retrieve the values between `min` and `max` as I have done for `min` and `max`?
If I use `(SUM(Id) - (MIN(Id)+MAX(Id))` I get the `sum` of `middle min` and `max`, but not the values I want.

EXAMPLES

```
Cod      |  Id

Stack       10
Stack       15
Stack       11
Stack       40
Overflow    1
Overflow    120
Overflow    15
Overflow    100
```

Required output

```
Cod         | Min   | Min_In_The_Middle | Max_In_The_Middle | Max

Stack         10          11                   15               40
Overflow      1           15                  100               120
```

Comment: What do you mean with middle - average perhaps? Or median?

Comment: show your input and required output

Comment: why? with 3 values it's perfect i have tried! Ref:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10206934/group-by-retrieve-3-values

Comment: Is your next question going to concern working with 5 values? Is this just a very long-winded route to asking for a pivot of an arbitrary number of columns?

Comment: good comment...but 3 values it's more simple usage than >3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just only one `[Table|[Clustered] Index]]Scan` (demo [here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/67157)):

```
SELECT  pvt.Cod,
        pvt.[1] AS MinValue,
        pvt.[2] AS MinInterValue,
        pvt.[3] AS MaxInterValue,
        pvt.[4] AS MaxValue
FROM
(
        SELECT  x.Cod, x.ID, x.RowNumAsc
        FROM
        (
                SELECT  *,
                        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY t.Cod ORDER BY t.ID ASC) RowNumAsc,
                        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY t.Cod ORDER BY t.ID DESC) RowNumDesc
                FROM    MyTable t
        ) x
        WHERE   x.RowNumAsc = 1 AND x.RowNumDesc = 4
        OR      x.RowNumAsc = 2 AND x.RowNumDesc = 3
        OR      x.RowNumAsc = 3 AND x.RowNumDesc = 2
        OR      x.RowNumAsc = 4 AND x.RowNumDesc = 1

) y
PIVOT   ( MAX(y.ID) FOR y.RowNumAsc IN ([1], [2], [3], [4]) ) pvt;
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what it means for your question to be tagged `plsql` **and** `sql-server`. But I'll assume you're working with a database system that supports CTEs and window functions.

To generalize what you're been trying to do, first assign row numbers to the rows, then use whatever technique you want to achieve the pivot:

```
;WITH OrderedValues as (
    SELECT Cod,Id,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Cod ORDER BY Id) as rn
       COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Cod) as Cnt
    FROM Table (NOLOCK)
), With4Values as (
    SELECT * from OrderedValues where Cnt=4
)
SELECT Cod,
    --However you want to do the pivot. Here I'll use MAX/CASE
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn=1 THEN Id END) as Value1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn=2 THEN Id END) as Value2,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn=3 THEN Id END) as Value3,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn=4 THEN Id END) as Value4
FROM
    With4Values
GROUP BY
    Cod
```

You can hopefully see that this is more easily extended to more columns than answering your overly specific questions about 3 rows, or 4 rows. But if you need to deal with an arbitrary number of columns, you'll have to switch to dynamic SQL.

Comment: don't work...it say With4Values.Cod it's not valid in select because it's not included in aggregation function or GROUP BY

Comment: Ah, sorry. It is just missing the outer group by though, I've edited it in now.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this, best of luck

```
WITH temp AS
         (SELECT   cod, MIN (ID) min_id, MAX (ID) max_id
              FROM tab
          GROUP BY cod
            HAVING COUNT (ID) = 4)
    SELECT code, temp.min_id,
           (SELECT   MIN (ID)
                FROM tab
               WHERE cod = temp.cod AND ID NOT IN (temp.min_id)
            GROUP BY cod) min_mid_id,
           (SELECT   MAX (ID)
                FROM tab
               WHERE cod = temp.cod AND ID NOT IN (temp.max_id)
            GROUP BY cod) max_min_id, temp.max_id
      FROM temp;
```

Comment: @Luigi: It's a huge difference in terms of performance between my solution and cyborg007's solution. My solution requires only one pass over data. This solution requires at least three.

Comment: execution time it's the same in my case...maybe your solution it's well formed...

Comment: @Luigi: Use [`SET STATISTICS IO, TIME ON/OFF`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184361.aspx) and look at `logical reads` (the number of 8KB data pages read from buffer) or (better) use [SQL Profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175047.aspx) and look at `Reads` and `Duration` from `SQL:BatchCompleted` events.

Answer (score 0):

I understand you want to exclude the extreme values and find min and max for the rest.
This is what I think of, but I had no chance to run and test it...

```
WITH Extremes AS ( SELECT Cod, MAX(ID) AS Id_Max, MIN(ID) AS Id_Min 
                    FROM [Table] a GROUP BY Cod)
SELECT 
  e.Cod,
  e.Id_Min,
  MIN(a.Id) AS id_Min_Middle,
  MAX(a.Id) AS id_Max_Middle,
  e.Id_Max
FROM Extremes e
LEFT JOIN [Table] a ON a.Cod = e.Cod AND a.Id > e.Id_Min AND a.Id < e.Id_Max
GROUP BY e.Cod
```